# Find spectrum equation of signal

Tags: fourier-analysis, signal-processing

I have the following graph and I'm trying to acquire the equation of the shown spectrum, but despite being a visually simple signal, I haven't been able to figure it out.

**Graph:**

[image]

**What I've tried:**

To me this looks like a DSB-modulated signal of triangular pulses cut at half by a low-pass filter, so the equation I came up with is the following:

$$
X(f)=4\left(
   tri\left({{f-1}\over{2}}\right)+
   tri\left({{f+1}\over{2}}\right)
\right)rect\left({{f}\over{2}}\right)
\\
X_{DSB}(f)={1 \over 2}X(f-9)+{1 \over 2}X(f+9)
$$

**Result:**

The resulting plot of $X(f)$ *(can be found [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=X(f)%3D4(tri((f%E2%88%921)%2F2)%2Btri((f%2B1)%2F2))rect(f%2F2)))* is nowhere near the one I'm trying to achieve.
[image]

**Question:**

What's the equation $X(f)$ of the depicted spectrum and where do I err in my attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research and experimentation, I figured out that the equation of the desired graph is:

$$
X(f)=4\ rect\left({f}\over{2}\right)-2\ tri\left(f\right)
\\
X_{DSB}(f)={1 \over 2}X(f-9)+{1 \over 2}X(f+9)
$$

**Result:**

The resulting plot of X(f) can be found [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=X(f)+%3D+(4rect(f%2F2)+-+2tri(f))).

[image]